# How can I execute a regular task using flask?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm writing a website using flask, the data of this site needs to be pull from another data source and stored in my local database, this task needs to be executed at 0:00 every day, so what's the most simple way to do this?

Comment: So you want celery solution or try @daoctor solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crontab` to do this.
this will run `/home/user/backup.sh` every day at 0:00
if you add this to your crontab file:
  `0 0 0 * * /home/user/backup.sh`